# Null Object Design Pattern in LinkedList

Tags: java, design-patterns, null-object-pattern

I am trying to Implement a doubly linked with null objects at the beginning and end of the list using null object design pattern. So an empty list will contain two null objects. So I wrote this code Does this follow null object design pattern? If not how can I achieve that. ANy suggestions will be appreciated.

Updated Code-

```
// Creating a doubly linked list.
        doubleLinkedList = new DoubleLinkedList();

    class DoubleLinkedList {

        private NewLink firstNode;
        private NewLink lastNode;
        private NewLink rootNode;



        public DoubleLinkedList() {

//So this satisfies my question that I have asked meaning null objects at beginning and last node or something else I have to do.
            firstNode = NewLink.NULL_NODE;
            lastNode  = NewLink.NULL_NODE;

        }

    }



    class NewLink {

        public String  data;
        public NewLink nextPointer;
        public NewLink previousPointer;


public static final NewLink NULL_NODE = new NewLink(); 



        public NewLink(String id) {

            data = id;

        }

public NewLink() {

    }
        // Overriding toString method to return the actual data of the node
        public String toString() {

            return "{" + data + "} ";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final NewLink NULL_NODE = new NewLink();
```

must be in `NewLink` class

so

```
firstNode = NewLink.NULL_NODE;
secondNode = NewLink.NULL_NODE;
```

also you can make all methods from `NewLink` - abstract
and make two nested classes: for NULL objects and for not NULL object.
It's can be very helpful in difficult situations

Comment: i updated the code as per your suggestions. let me know if it is right now?

Answer (score 4):

No, your code doesn't implement `Null Object Design Pattern`. Its essence is not to use `null` but to create an object which will represent the `null`.

For example:

```
public static final NewLink NULL_NODE = new NewLink();
```

And then:

```
firstNode = NULL_NODE;
lastNode  = NULL_NODE;
```

Comment: @Nevzz03 - See `user1143825` answer for moving the definition to the other class. It is more logical.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Null object design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) if we want to assign some default behaviors (or prevent some behaviors to happen as a default behavior) 
For example using Null object pattern we can replace this code :

```
if(myObj!=null) 
myObj.DoSomething();
else
DoSomethingElse();
```

wtih this one:

```
myObj.DoSomething() //assuming that myObj can be a Null object (not a null reference) that has implemented DoSomethingElse when you ask it to DoSomething()
```

Thus a Null Object design pattern actually uses a default object reference (not a null reference )